# How to include a if check into a for loop

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement, pyomo

I try add a constraint expressions to a python/pyomo model:
the code I tried is this:

```
for r_k in VAR1: 
    for p_v in VAR2:
        for b_n in VAR3:
            IF mix[b_n][p_v]() >= 0:
                model.cons.add(model.func2[r_k,b_n,p_v]*q1[b_n][p_v] - model.func1[r_k,b_n,p_v] ==0)
```

If I leave the `IF` loop away it runs fine. The code above produces a Syntax error. 
Only downside is it creates 1000s of extra mathematically trivial constraints that are not needed.
"mix" is only a sparsely populated "binary" dictionary (i.e. mostly zeros, a few ones in between). A constraint is only needed where there is a "1".
It seems there is an issue with evaluating/calling the dictionary values within the for loops.
Any idea how to resolve this would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two errors in your code:

- `if` is lowercase in Python. `IF` does **NOT** exist in any of the standard modules
- assuming `mix` is a dicitonary, you can't call it. By adding braces `()` behind a variable or anything in the scope, you tell python to treat it as a callable and try to execute it.

Assuming the rest of your code works fine, this should solve your problem:

```
for r_k in VAR1: 
    for p_v in VAR2:
        for b_n in VAR3:
            if mix[b_n][p_v] >= 0:
                model.cons.add(model.func2[r_k, b_n, p_v] * q1[b_n][p_v] - model.func1[r_k, b_n, p_v] == 0)
```

Further remarks:

- `if` (and `elif`, `else`) is **NOT** a loop, it is a conditional statement! `for` or `while` are loops.
- you check for `mix[b_n][p_v] >= 0`, but state that a constraint is only needed when *"there is a "1""*. So shouldn't your condition be `mix[b_n][p_v] > 0` or even more explicitly `mix[b_n][p_v] == 1`? (Explicit is better than implicit, see [The Zen of Python, second statement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3))

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I will definitely try the```==1```. re loop, sorry i am still pretty new to programming, so not that good yet with all the terms.

Comment: You are welcome and no problem at all! I'm glad I was able to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove calling `mix`:

```
for r_k in VAR1: 
    for p_v in VAR2:
        for b_n in VAR3:
            IF mix[b_n][p_v] >= 0:
                model.cons.add(model.func2[r_k,b_n,p_v]*q1[b_n][p_v] - model.func1[r_k,b_n,p_v] ==0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If i correctly understood the problem , the constraint is only added to the model when the value of mix dictionary for some key evaluates to 1.

if so

in your code `IF mix[b_n][p_v]() >= 0:`

here in if statement you are adding constraint for every value be it 0 or 1. 
try

`for r_k in VAR1: 
    for p_v in VAR2:
        for b_n in VAR3:
            if mix[b_n][p_v] == 1:
                model.cons.add(model.func2[r_k,b_n,p_v]*q1[b_n][p_v] -model.func1[r_k,b_n,p_v] ==0)`

Answer (score 0):

`IF` should be `if`. Lowercase not uppercase.

Comment: thanks a lot, this worked right away. sometimes one does not see the forest because of too many trees.

Comment: thanks to all who answered so quick. i tried to upvote. but i am still quite new, so do not have enough reputation yet. hopefully get there one day. :-)